# RVM installing Ruby for i386 rather than x86_64 on OSX 10.8.2

Tags: ruby, rvm, x86-64, i386

I've installed Ruby/Gem/Rails on two different OSX 10.8.2 machines.  One is working fine and the other appears to work until I attempt to install a gem that includes native code like pg.  When I do

```
gem install pg -v 0.12.2
```

it fails out with a "Can't find the PostgeSQL client library (libpq).

If I look at mkmf.log I see:

`have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- no "gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin12.2.0 -I/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/include -I/Users/brian/.rvm/usr/include -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib -L. -L/Users/brian/.rvm/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib     -lruby.1.9.1 -lpq  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_PQconnectdb", referenced from:
      _t in ccLXteQk.o`

I believe this is being caused because the library that is being ignored is a 64-bit library (like I want) but my ruby install is 32-bit (for some reason).  As evidence, on the machine that works I see

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/ruby/config.h
```

on the one that fails

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-darwin12.2.0/ruby/config.h
```

Sorry for the long explanation.  I've tried lots of things to try to set the architecture for

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

which is producing those directories.  None of my efforts have induced the "bad" machine to produce an include directory in keeping with a desired 64-bit binary.  I didn't knowingly set the architecture on either of these builds so I'm perplexed at this point what in the environment of the "bad" machine is causing the ruby install to think it should build 32-bit binaries. Any ideas?

Comment: What does ~/.rvmrc look like on the one that's failing?

Comment: Neither machine had a .rvmrc file but I did create one at one point on the failing machine to try to get past this.  Although it did not change the outcome, that file - which I created by hand - has only this line: rvm_archflags="-arch x86_64"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your arch flags to that i do believe. Like `gem install pg -- --arch-flags='i386'`

or whatever pg accepts for arch flags. Should also be a flag you can pass to define the arch type (causing it to find that)

You can also say `gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/path/to/pg/include --with-pg-dir=/path/to/pg_config`

Comment: I will try again the first suggestion you are sharing as it is closest to what I need although I believe the basic problem is back with the installation of Ruby as a starting point.  There is a header file (config.h) which has 32-bit (i386) definitions in it and I've not been able to prevent that from being generated when running RVM to install Ruby.

Comment: Then if you need to build a 32bit ruby, again, use the ARCHFLAGS setting manually by passing them to the build process. 

You can even ensure this is the default by adding the ```rvm_archflags="-arch i386"``` to your ```$HOME/.rvmrc``` file which will apply to all future builds.

You say you added this file previously, however you added the wrong arch flag settings so everything kept defaulting to 64bit builds.

Comment: Thanks again - The ruby install is a 32-bit install but that is not what I want.  I want 64-bit builds.   I'm acting on the understanding that i386 is 32-bits and x86_64 is the 64-bit flag.  Something in the communication seems like maybe I hadn't made that clear or I'm misreading your direction.

Comment: Uninstall that ruby. IF its 32bit then any libraries it will look for and use will be 32bit. 

Uninstall it, run ```rvm cleanup sources```, add the ```rvm_archflags='--arch x86_64'``` in your $HOME/.rvmrc, ```export ARCHFLAGS='--arch x86_64'``` in the shell, and then run the ruby install again. Once that is complete, you should have a 64-bit ruby install. If not, your compiler is busted, or you're UNsetting the archflag in your environment in a place not under RVM control. If so, then install your remaining gems as needed. Be sure the installed postgresql is the 64bit version as well.

Comment: Hey ddd - thanks again.  We are on the same page at this point. The failure again was after all the PG gem install failed because I had 64-bit pg libraries but the ruby install insisted on producing a 32 bit version.  After trying your suggestion I was again getting the same results.  I resorted to looking through the rvm scripts and eventually found that I could pass '--arch x86_64' to rvm directly.  Installing with 'rvm --arch x86_64 install 1.9.3' did the trick.  I don't know why this was not getting picked up in ~/.rvmrc for example but I'll take it. Just --64 would have worked as well.

Comment: I would report that at https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues as that is definitely not expected behaviour.